# Using symmetry of integrand and domain to evaluate area integrals

Tags: integration, area, symmetry, integral-domain

Using symmetries to evaluate integrals is not something that I have ever been shown or taught and I have come across a problem that I am very unsure of my answers to. Any help would be appreciated!

I have shown that
$$I=\iint_A x^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e}\right)$$
where $A$ is the intersection of the interior of the unit circle with the first quadrant.

Now, with $D$ as the interior of the unit circle, I would like to find the following using just symmetry arguments:

$$I_1=\iint_D x^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy,\;I_2=\iint_D y^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy,\;I_3=\iint_D xye^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$

$I_1$: The integrand of $I$ is invariant to both $x\mapsto-x$, $y\mapsto-y$, and any composition of the two. The first mapping would change $I$ to the integral over the second quadrant, the second mapping gives the fourth quadrant, and applying both gives the third quadrant.
Since $I_1$ is the sum of the integral over each quadrant,
$$I_1=4\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)=\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e}\right)$$

$I_2$: This integral has the same integrand with a reflection in the line $y=x$. I know that noting the integrals of $sin^2$ and $cos^2$ are equal over $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, combined with the above justification for $I_1$, gives $I_2=I_1$ (?). I cannot think of a way to justify this part without comparing the calculation of the integral instead of using the $y=x$ reflection.

$I_3$: For this I feel like there is no choice but to calculate the integral explicitly for the first quadrant and then the mappings mentioned for $I_1$ show that the four quadrants cancel each other for this integral and so $I_3=0$.

I would like to know to what extent my method is correct and rigorous, how is best to justify a symmetry argument like for $I_1$, and if there is a way to evaluate the second/third integrals without calculating any integrals. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would have $I_3=0$ because the integrand is odd. In particular,

$$\iint_A (-x)ye^{-(-x)^2-y^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = -I \\\\
\iint_A x(-y)e^{-x^2-(-y)^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = -I \\\\
\iint_A (-x)(-y)e^{-(-x)^2-(-y)^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = I$$

so that $\iint_Dxye^{-x^2-y^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=I-I-I+I=0$. You don't even need to know the value of $I$ to arrive at this.

Comment: OK great thank you, I think I overcomplicated the third one. Is there a solution for $I_2$ without the need for calculation?